# Code to demonstrate CFNetwork changes in iOS SDK 7.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cfnetwork

Can anyone provide code or logic that can demonstrate CFNetwork compatibility changes in iOS SDK 7.1?

Notes by Apple:

**CFNetwork**

Notes
A compatibility behavior has been added to address an issue where some web servers would send the wrong Content-Length value for “Content-Encoding: gzip” content. Previously, NSURLConnection and NSURLSession would send a “network connection was lost” / NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost (-1005) error in this situation.

The compatibility behavior applies only if the Content-Length value exactly matches the expanded gzip’d content. It won’t apply for “off by 1” or similar miscounting.*